# ¿Cómo crear un cron job en Laravel para ejecutar una acción por única vez?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, cronjobs

Necesito un cron job que ejecute una modificación dentro de la base de datos, en el momento que se cumplan 6 meses después de que el usuario haya presionado un botón.

Encontré documentación al respecto de los cron job pero no resultaron muy claros los ejemplos para mí, ni encontré una forma de ejecutarlos una sola vez ni de cómo ejecutarlos a los 6 meses de haber presionado un botón.

Llevo desarrollado lo siguiente:

1. Un comando creado con las instrucciones de Laravel

   ```
    class DeleteItem extends Command
    {
        /**
         * The name and signature of the console command.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $signature = 'delete:item';

        /**
         * The console command description.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $description = 'Eliminación después de 6 meses';

        /**
         * Create a new command instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            $item = Item::find(1);
            $item->delete();
            Log::info('Eliminando...');
        }
    }
   ```
2. Y en el kernel.php

   ```
    <?php

    namespace App\Console;

    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    {
        /**
         * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $commands = [
            'App\Console\Commands\DeleteItem',
        ];


        /**
         * Define the application's command schedule.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
         * @return void
         */
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\ItemController@delete')->everyMinute();
        }

        /**
         * Register the commands for the application.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function commands()
        {
            $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

            require base_path('routes/console.php');
        }
    }
   ```

Y no sé cómo ejecutarlo desde una función del controlador.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde yo sé, no puedes realizar llamadas a funciones de un controlador desde un schedule (O no deberías).

Lo que yo suelo hacer es lo siguiente:

1- Creo una clase Job que se va a encargar de gestionar la lógica cada plazo de tiempo:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#generating-job-classes

2- Añado ese Job a `Console/Kernel` añadiendo la periodicidad con la que se va a ejecutar:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs

Quedando de la siguiente forma si llamaramos al Job `DeleteItemJob`:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new DeleteItemJob)->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

Para la duda que tienes sobre los 6 meses, es el propio Job el que tiene que comprobar que se han superado los 6 meses o no (p.ej almacenar la última pulsación en base de datos o algo así)

Answer (score 0):

No es posible ejecutar la acción de un controlador desde un cron-job. La tareas programadas sólo ejecutan comandos o jobs -> https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling.

```
$schedule->command('delete:item')->everyMinute()
$schedule->job(new DeleteItem)->everyMinute();
```

Si necesitas que ese código corra desde un comando y un controlador, mete el código en un job.

Por otro lado, para que se ejecute a los 6 meses de haber ejecutado la acción, debes almacenar la fecha en la que el usuario presionó el botón y programar un cron-job que ejecute un comando. Programalo a para que corra todas los dias de magrugada.

Este comando debe solicitar los elementos de la tabla cuya fecha de acción (presionar botón) sea igual o superior a 6 meses meses. Cuando lo proceses, márcalo como procesado para no procesarlo dos veces.

Answer (score 0):

De la forma que ejecuto un command es haciendo uso del crontab de linux (en el caso que tu uses linux tambien)

para agregar uno nuevo lo haces con el comando

```
sudo crontab -e
```

cuando lo haces por primera vez te solicitará el editor con el que deseas trabajar

al final del todo agregas las opciones

EL formato es el siguiente
[minute] [hour] [day of month] [month] [day of week] [command]

En este enlace podrás encontrar como agregar los intervalos de tiempo que desees
https://crontab.guru/

por ejemplo en mi caso, tengo una tarea de registro de asistencias, el cual se tienen que bloquear 2 dias despues de la fecha de vencimiento

```
*/180 7 * * * * cd /var/www/dir && php artisan bloquear:asistencia >> /var/www/dir/asistencia.log
```

ahora lo que hace es ejecutar cada 180minutos ,toda hora, todos los días, todos los días de la semana, ubicarse en el directorio dir (que es el del proyecto) y ejecutar el command de laravel y la salida de ese command (yo tengo un echo) lo añada a un log

espero te sirva de ayuda